# Python Regex to match a all variations of a keyword except if preceded by a capitalized word

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a Python Regex to match a all variations of a keyword except if preceded by a capitalized word -> except when that capitalized word is the start of a sentence. Also excludes words between brackets.

for example:

```
keyword = 'public record'
string1 = 'Hello. His public records are available at city hall.' #match public records His is the start of a sentence so we ignore that it is capitalized and match
string2 = 'his records are at Newsom Public Record DataBase'      #nomatch
string3 = 'Public records may be available online'                #match Public records
string4 = '[public records](http:/....)'                          #nomatch
```

So far I have tried:

```
pattern = f'(?<!\[)(?i)\\w*{keyword}\\w*'   #Doesn't  take into account preceding capitalized words
pattern = f'(?<![A-Z][\w-]\s)(?<!\[)(?i)\\w*{keyword}\\w*' #Doesn't work for cap words > 2 chara
```

Comment: `His public records` is preceded by capitalized word `his`, so it shouldn't be match

Comment: But that His is a start of a sentence so I want that to match.

Comment: With this kind of logic imo it would be better to do some hybrid solution: splitting into words + regex. Is it acceptable, or does it have to be done with single regex?

Comment: I'll try that. Find a positive match for the simple pattern, split tokens and test surrounding words.

Would still be nice to know if a regex is possible for personal enrichment though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the various allowed beginnings, i.e. start of sentence + cap word, non-cap word or beginning of string, and then assert that the keyword follows with a lookahead:

```
pattern = r'(\. [A-Z]\w* |\W[^A-Z]\w* |^)(?=[pP]ublic [rR]ecord)'
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me alot. Little tweaking for my use case, but it works! Thank you good sir

Comment: Came up with:
`pattern = f'([\.\!\?] [A-Z]\w* |\\b[^A-Z\s][a-z]+\\b |[\.\?\!] |^|[\-\"\'])(?=(\\w*{kw}\\w*))'`
from your answer